# XGBoost Log Loss different from GridSearchCV Log Loss

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, ensemble-modeling, grid-search

I have a classification problem where I am trying to predict if the data returns a 1 or 0. So your classic binary classification. I have my set of data that I have split into the dependent variables (ones I am training on) and the independent variable (my target that I am predicting, either a 0 or 1). I am using log loss as the scoring metric for my model.

Firstly, I am using the cv function in xgboost to figure out the number of estimators I need as it stops when the log loss has not improved over 50 rounds. I then train my model and predict. My code is below:

```
def modelfit(alg, dtrain, dtarget, useTrainCV=True, cv_folds=5, early_stopping_rounds=50):
    
    if useTrainCV:
        # gets the xgb parameters specifically.
        xgb_param = alg.get_xgb_params()
        
        # this is the internal xgb data frame that is for efficiency. We map the training data to the labels.
        xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(dtrain.values, label=dtarget)
        
        # this performs cross validation on the dataset. As our data is not really time dependent we can afford to cross
        # validate. It stops when it hasnt improved for 50 rounds. This is only for determining n_estimators
        cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], nfold=cv_folds,
            metrics='logloss', early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
                
        print(f'Optimal n_estimators - {cvresult.shape[0]}')
        
        # this sets the most optimal n_estimators parameter into the booster.
        alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])
            
    # fit the algorithm on the data and set evaluation metric
    alg.fit(dtrain.values, dtarget, eval_metric='logloss', eval_set=[(dtrain.values, dtarget)])
    
    print(alg.evals_result())
        
    # predict training set:
    dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(dtrain.values)
    print(dtrain_predictions)
    dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(dtrain.values)[:,1]
        
    # print model report:
    print("\nModel Report")
    print("Log Loss Score (Train): %f" % metrics.log_loss(dtarget, dtrain_predprob))
```

I then run this function on this particular XGBoostClassifier:

```
#Choose all predictors
xgb1 = XGBClassifier(
 learning_rate =0.1,
 n_estimators=1000,
 max_depth=5,
 min_child_weight=1,
 gamma=0,
 subsample=0.8,
 colsample_bytree=0.8,
 objective= 'binary:logistic',
 scale_pos_weight=1, 
 nthread=-1,
 seed=27)

modelfit(xgb1, X, y)
```

The log loss value that is returned is: 0.577496 and the number of estimators is 65.

I then turn to GridSearchCV to tune the other parameters and I start with:

```
param_test1 = {
 'max_depth' : range(1,10),
 'min_child_weight' : range(1,6)
}
```

Note how the original max depth and min child weight are contained within these ranges that I used in the xgb1 classifier.

```
xgb2 = XGBClassifier(
        learning_rate =0.1, 
        n_estimators=65,
        max_depth=5,
        min_child_weight=1, 
        gamma=0, 
        subsample=0.8, 
        colsample_bytree=0.8,
        objective= 'binary:logistic',
        nthread=-1,
        scale_pos_weight=1, 
        seed=27
)

gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = xgb2, 
    param_grid = param_test1, scoring='neg_log_loss', n_jobs=-1, cv=5
)

gsearch1.fit(X, y)
gsearch1.best_params_, gsearch1.best_score_
```

However, this returns me with:

```
(
{'max_depth': 1, 'min_child_weight': 1}, -0.6275341839742403
)
```

So my question is how has the grid search said the best parameters are `max_depth = 1` and `min_child_weight = 1` and the log loss is 0.628 when previously before using GridSearchCV my model returned a better log loss of 0.577 with `max_depth = 5` and `min_child_weight = 1`?

Any help would be appreciated, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `modelfit` prints the training score, but `GridSearchCV` bases its decisions on the out-of-fold average (and in particular `best_score_` is an out-of-fold average score).  This is an unfair comparison, and in particular your 0.577 is probably quite optimistically biased.

Comment: Interesting - but I am using 'neg_log_loss' as the scoring method in ```GridSearchCV```. So how do I compare the best result from GridSearchCV to the result I get from ```modelfit``` ?

Comment: Ideally, get a cross-validation score in `modelfit` instead of the training score.  If you'll always be using `useTrainCV=True`, the array `cvresult` has what you need.

Comment: But what I'm struggling to understand is how comes when I use ```xgb.cv()``` I get a logloss score of 0.577. But then when I try to use ```GridSearchCV``` how can I tell it to find the parameters that will optimise my logloss score the most? As when I do it and insert the parameters it found - it gives a worse score than my original?

Comment: @SeanO'Connor, the first and third sentences of your comment are addressed in my answer.  For the second, you are already doing it correctly.  Just note that GridSearchCV is optimizing for the test-fold score, not train-folds (as it should!).

Comment: Ah okay understood. So how would I make it optimise for the train folds instead of the test folds?

Comment: @SeanO'Connor you **really shouldn't** do that; you'll just encourage the search to select the most-overfit model.  That said, you can get train-fold scoring by setting `return_train_score=True`, and you can make the selection of best model depend on that by using a function as the `refit` parameter, which will have access to all the fields of `cv_results_`.

Comment: Understood, so to summarise. When I used GridSearchCV it would be best for me to return ```gsearch1.best_estimator_``` to return what estimator did best with certain parameters and then use that estimator to predict? And then calculate the logloss on those predictions?